# using Crystal Reports 8.5 + VB 6.0 for a project, what .Dlls do we need to include while preparing a setup file for the project?

Tags: dll, vb6, crystal-reports

did you know that 
using Crystal Reports 8.5 + VB 6.0 for a project, what .Dlls we need to include while preparing a setup file for the project?

The project executes on my own computer properly but it does not execute on user's computer.

The user says: "  I get this error when I wanna to execute a report::  'physical database not found' "

I use SQL server 2000 as data source.

Answer (score 3):

There are no merge modules available with Crystal 8.5 - I ended up creating my own MSI package for this.

[This page](http://www.installshield.com//downloads/modules.asp?prod=cx&lan=english) has a link to merge modules for Crystal 8.5 (as well as 8)

Comment: BTW, what is a merge module and how do I use it in order to fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: CodeByMoonlight,
I use "Package and Deployment wizard" of visual studio for making a setup file......What do you think? Is it a good choice or else?

Comment: A merge module is a collection of DLLs intended to be included as part of an install package, and usable by apps like InstallShield. The Package and Deployment Wizard is very old and doesn't work too well with modern systems.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports includes a Merged Module that you can include into your setup files. In the merged module you can turn on and off which features(dlls) will be included into your setup file.

Comment: Where can I find the merged module?

Comment: look in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules

Answer (score 0):

Hi and Thank you for your attentions.

I found the answer and it was just adding "p2soledb.dll" to my setup package.